# C# attribute for ASHX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I have some ashx files and have the same code like this:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

And I'm thinking is there any way to do like this:

```
[EnableCors]
public class ThemeHandler : IHttpHandler
{        
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {}
}
```

and if the Handler with [EnableCors] Attribute ,then include the code like top.

Comment: nope. ashx are pretty bare bones. you could implement your own.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If you want to add the header at a centralized location, you could try adding it to `Application_BeginRequest`. However, at that point, IIS does not know yet which handler will handle the request, so you need to use another criterion to make the decision whether or not to include the header.

Comment: As an alternative to what @Heinzi said you could write it as an HttpModule - as quick Google found this: https://gist.github.com/markrendle/6579306